# How to log FVector in unreal engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

FVector ActorLocation = GetActorLocation();

UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Actor location: %f"), ActorLocation);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't log an `FVector` directly. You need to convert it to an `FString` and then use `%s` (not `%f`) and finally `operator*` for dereferencing.

This should work

```
UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Actor location: %s"), *ActorLocation.ToString());
```